# Solutions With Non-Negative Elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have understood the formula for the number of solutions in the positive integers of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n$$ which is

$${n-1 \choose r-1}$$

It can be looked at as the way to divide $n$ elements into $r$ parts, there are $n-1$ possible places to place a divider, and to divide into $r$ parts, there are $r-1$ dividers needed.

But when the equation can include a part with $0$ elements, the formula is as follows:
$${n+r-1 \choose r-1}$$
Is the reason is that we can add one more divider to each part so we will create another part with $0$ elements in it?

Comment: The formulas you stated are for the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n$ in the positive integers and non-negative integers.  The term partition refers to the ways of expressing a positive integer as a sum of positive integers.  For instance, \begin{align*}5 & = 5\\ & = 4 + 1\\ & = 3 + 2\\ & = 3 + 1 + 1\\ &  = 2 + 2 + 1\\ & = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1\\ & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\end{align*}  Which concept do you have in mind?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig the concept of balls/stars and dividers

Comment: I have edited your question.  Please check what I have written to see if I have captured what you are trying to ask.  If not, please edit accordingly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes that what I have meant.
In 4+1 and 3+2 $n=5$ and $r=2$ so it is ${4 \choose 1}$?

Comment: The number of solutions in the positive integers of the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 5$ is $\binom{4}{1}$.  They are $(4, 1)$, $(3, 2)$, $(2, 3)$, $(1, 4)$.  The number of solutions in the nonnegative integers of the same equation is $\binom{5 + 1}{1} = \binom{6}{1}$.  They are $(5, 0)$, $(4, 1)$, $(3, 2)$, $(2, 3)$, $(1, 4)$, $(0, 5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wish to solve the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n$$
in the nonnegative integers, we can regard a particular solution as a choice of where to insert $r - 1$ addition signs into a row of $n$ ones.  For instance, the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 2$ of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 12$$
corresponds to the choice 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
while the solution $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 5$ corresponds to the choice
$$1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1$$
That is, a particular solution corresponds to a choice of which $r - 1$ of the $n + r - 1$ symbols ($n$ ones and $r - 1$ addition signs) will be addition signs.  The number of ways we can do this is 
$$\binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1}$$
In the terminology you used, the addition signs are the dividers and the ones are the objects we are dividing into $r$ possibly empty parts.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to count the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_r=n$ where the $x_i$ are nonnegative integers

is to substitute $y_i=x_i+1$ for $1\le i\le r$, $\;\;$so $y_i>0$ for each $i$, and $x_i=y_1-1$ gives

$(y_1-1)+\cdots+(y_r-1)=n\;$ or $\;\;y_1+\cdots+y_r=n+r$.

Using your formula, this has $\dbinom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ solutions in positive integers.